# How Do I Model My Results Using Java Collections?

Tags: java

I have an application which is using Drools Expert to evaluate some rules. The results will be of this type:

```
String, String, Integer
```

A typical result example is:

```
"Rule 1", "RED",   1
"Rule 2", "AMBER", 2
"Rule 3", "GREEN", 1
"Rule 4", "INFO",  3
```

The first element is a key. So I am thinking of using a Map structure. The last field is an integer specified via an enum. I want to be able to pick from this list of results the rule with the maximum priority (which is the last field).

What is the best way to structure this in terms of using the Java collections library? Is the Map the best?

Comment: You create a "bean" that has your three values, then put that into a `Collection`.  The choice of the collection depends on how you plan to use the data and what rules you want to impose in uniqueness.  The most common are `List`, 'Map', or 'Set', each having specific implementations that offer varying arrays of features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be able to pick from this list of results the rule with the maximum priority (which is the last field).

You could package the data into a class that is comparable based on the last field, and then use a [`PriorityQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

```
class Data implements Comparable<Data> {
    private String rule;
    private String other;
    private int priority;

    ...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Data other) {
        return Integer.compare(priority, other.priority);
    }
}
```

Now, you can use a `PriorityQueue<Data>`.

Comment: Do I initialise it like this: PriorityQueue<Data> q = new PriorityQueue<Data>(10); ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Queue<Result> resultList = new PriorityQueue<Result>();

public class Result implements Comparable<Result>{

    private String ruleText;
    private String text; // 2. value
    private int priority;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Result result) {
        return new Integer(priority).compareTo(result.getPriority());
    }

    public String getRuleText() {
        return ruleText;
    }

    public void setRuleText(String ruleText) {
        this.ruleText = ruleText;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Map are the best to store if you have something termed as key in your data collection. For prioritization, its best to use PriorityQueue.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to create an Object implementing comparable.

```
class Rule implements Comparable<Rule>{
    String firstPart;
    String secondPart;
    int priority;
    //constructor
    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Rule other){
         return Integer.compare(this.priority, other.priority);
    }
}
```

Then you just put them all in a `TreeSet<Rule>` and iterate on it, they will come out sorted. Or you can store them in list and call `Collections.sort(list)`.